# Will re-formatting a hard drive get rid Of Symantec's PGP disk encryption?

Tags: disk-encryption, pgp

My machine has it's whole disk encrypted with Symantec PGP technology, the one that brings up the grey screen for a password before the operating system boots. Can I reformat the hard drive, and re-install the operating system without removing the encryption first?

What I mean is can I still boot an installation disc, or will the disk encryption block it? I don't care about what's currently on the hard disk, I just want the encryption gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symantec PGP does not limit access to the BIOS of your machine. It basically acts like a bootloader that decrypts your information once the proper passkey has been entered. You can still select another boot device like a DVD, and you can reformat the drive.

The only thing you will not be able to do is read the encrypted information on the drive, but I'm sure you're already aware of this.